# Grouping in drop down list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, controls

I am working on MVC. I need to achieve cascading drop down list on client side. The challenge is I just want to have one drop down list instead of 2. 
I have data in following order. Department & sub department

- Drinks

  - Soda
  - Juices
  - Water
- Confectionery

  - Cookies
  - Crisps
  - Chocolates

I want to show a drop drown list with all the Departments in it and a plus sign on left. So initially drop down list will show following

- (+) Drinks
- (+) Confectionery

Then if user clicks on Drinks. Drop down list will show like this

- (-) Drinks

  - Juices
  - Soda
  - Water
- (+) Confectionery

Does any one know how to achieve this on client side? Either by third party open source controls or entirely by JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Check this  May be you looking for this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fv8n1ang/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a drop down list. I need drop down list and extension should be within the same drop down list

Comment: any one with any suggestions?